# How to escape character "{%" in ansible variables

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have a yml file containing usernames and password hashes, like this:

```
  users:
  - name: eucariot
    pwd_hash: $1c$FCM#Y+8Z:T$/l>IX1tZG%Fh~u&q\Xq6fd7dT|>*,8>G8y:f38{-$
  - name: test
    pwd_hash: $1a$eWcH'5dD~1$l<vvDig#@.)I|;ZASgH'%Kv~N)&DA=[i<R@.'{%>$
```

Then I refer to it from Jinja template. It works perfectly for the user "eucariot", while fails for "test", because its hash contains "{%".

Running the playbook return an error:

```
template error while templating string: tag name expected. String: $1a$eWcH'5dD~1$l<vvDig#@.)I|;ZASgH'%Kv~N)&DA=[i<R@.'{%>$"}
```

I found the way how to escape such character by using !unsafe before the string, but problem is such file is created automatically by script and I don't know how to put "!unsafe" there.

Answer (score -2):

Looks like the following worked for me:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ \"$1a$eWcH'5dD~1$l<vvDig#@.)I|;ZASgH'%Kv~N)&DA=[i<R@.'{%>$\"}}"
```

Note the `"{{ \"\" }}"`